# Filtering a Listbox using an Edit box

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6, tlistbox

I'm trying to filter a listbox in Delphi using an Edit box, but it's not working.  Here's my code based on the OnChange event of an Edit box.

```
procedure TReportDlgForm.FilterEditOnChange(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  ListBox1.Items.BeginUpdate;
  try
    for I := 0 to ListBox1.Items.Count - 1 do
      ListBox1.Selected[I] := ContainsText(ListBox1.Items[I], FilterEdit.Text);
  finally
    ListBox1.Items.EndUpdate;
  end;
end;
```

I'm hoping that when I type in my edit box that the Listbox items will filter.

Comment: *Filter* in what way exactly?  All you are doing is highlighting items based on whether they match the text. Do you have `MultiSelect` enabled on the ListBox? What are you really trying to accomplish? Perhaps you are actually trying to hide non-matching items instead? If so, you will have to keep your main string list separate from the ListBox itself, then you can `Clear()` the ListBox and `Add()` the matching items to it as needed. Or, store the filtered results in a separate list, and use the ListBox in virtual mode to display that list.

Comment: @Remy - I do not have MutiSelect enabled on the ListBox.  I would like as the user types a string in the Edit Box, that only entries containing the string appear, and non-matching entries are hidden in the ListBox.  For example, let's say I initially have 40 entries displayed in the ListBox.  As the user types in the Edit Box, the number of entries in the ListBox decreases to only show matching entries based on what the user typed in the Edit Box.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must keep values from your list box in some variable and make search in this variable, not in ListBox items! In ListBox we only going to show result of search.

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Edit1: TEdit;
    ListBox1: TListBox;
    procedure Edit1Change(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    FList: TStringList;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

uses
  System.StrUtils;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Edit1Change(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: Integer;
  S: String;
begin
  ListBox1.Items.BeginUpdate;
  try
    ListBox1.Clear;
    if Edit1.GetTextLen > 0 then begin
      S := Edit1.Text;
      for I := 0 to FList.Count - 1 do begin
        if ContainsText(FList[I], S) then
          ListBox1.Items.Add(FList[I]);
      end;
    end;
  finally
    ListBox1.Items.EndUpdate;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FList := TStringList.Create;
  FList.Assign(ListBox1.Items);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FList.Free;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the value you want to search for in the `ItemData.detail` of the `TlistBoxItem` then you can call something like this:

```
procedure TmyForm.FilterLst(Astr: string);  
begin  
  MyListBox.FilterPredicate := function(X: string): Boolean  
    begin  
      var  
        str: String := Astr;  
      Result := Trim(str).IsEmpty or X.ToLower.Contains(str.ToLower);  
    end;  
end;
```